# How to post XML document to HTTP with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, webrequest, xmldocument, webresponse

I'm looking for help with posting my XML document to a url in VB.NET. Here's what I have so far ...

```
  Public Shared xml As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()

    Public Shared Sub Main()

        Dim root As XmlElement
        root = xml.CreateElement("root")
        xml.AppendChild(root)

        Dim username As XmlElement
        username = xml.CreateElement("username")
        username.InnerText = _username
        root.AppendChild(username)

        xml.Save(Console.Out)

        Dim url = "https://mydomain.com"
        Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        req.Method = "POST"
        req.ContentType = "application/xml"
        req.Headers.Add("Custom: API_Method")

        Console.WriteLine(req.Headers.ToString())
```

This is where things go awry:

I want to post the xml, and then print the results to console.

```
        Dim newStream As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
        xml.Save(newStream)

        Dim response As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString())
 End Sub
```

Comment: Please see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.contentlength.aspx)

Comment: I've seen this, but I don't fully follow it. xml.length does not work. What is byteArray?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially what I was after:

```
xml.Save(req.GetRequestStream())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to take care about the length, it is also possible to use the WebClient.UploadData method.

I adapted your snippet slightly in this way.

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Public Module Module1

    Public xml As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()

    Public Sub Main()

        Dim root As XmlElement
        root = xml.CreateElement("root")
        xml.AppendChild(root)

        Dim username As XmlElement
        username = xml.CreateElement("username")
        username.InnerText = "user1"
        root.AppendChild(username)

        Dim url = "http://mydomain.com"
        Dim client As New WebClient

        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml")
        client.Headers.Add("Custom: API_Method")
        Dim sentXml As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml.OuterXml)
        Dim response As Byte() = client.UploadData(url, "POST", sentXml)

        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString())

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: xml.Save(req.GetRequestStream()) is now warning: Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified

Comment: I changed a little bit the original to use the WebClient object.

Comment: Content-length is as required header for this API.